# Angular- why does / in href stop flickering?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I'm encountering some strange behavior in one of my web apps when using Angular's routeProvider as a template engine. Although it works, it doesn't make sense to me why it works.

Whats happening is that during transitions from page to page (mostly in safari/mobile safari) you will see the page you're transitioning to flicker in the front of view before transitioning in. How I fixed this problem is just by adding a slash to the end of the href's url, ex:`href="#/home/"` instead of `href="#/home` . Does anyone out there know why adding a "/" to the url would fix such a problem?

I set up the routeProvider like this:

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
      controller : 'HomeCtrl',
      templateUrl : './home.html'
    }).when('/pageTwo', {
      controller : 'twoCtrl',
      templateUrl : './pageTwo.html'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
  })
```

My html like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#/home" class="bt-icon">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/pageTwo" class="bt-icon">TWO</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and css like this:

```
.view-animate-container {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.view-animate {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.view-animate.ng-enter, .view-animate.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.view-animate.ng-enter {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(20%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0);
}
.view-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity:1;
}
.view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-20%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, 0);
    opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you link to the hash instead of the route itself?

Have you tried changing your links to `<a href="/home">Home</a>` instead of `href="#/home"` ?

Angular will manage the hash for you, (or not, if your browser supports pushState).

Comment: It's because I am using angular's Hashbang mode of setting the location which requires the hash. Instead of HTML5 Mode, which doesn't.[the doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location)

Comment: Even with hashbang mode, I thought you would link directly and ng would manage your hash.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm not 100% sure since I am fairly new to angular. But when I remove the hash the href breaks.